# How to run block of code in Postgres asynchronously (like a job)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbms-job

Can we execute a block of code outside of current session?
In other words, delegate the execution to another working thread, something like a `dbms_job.submit` in Oracle.

I found only solutions involving external tools like Cron, but do not see any options to do it using PostgreSQL DBMS itself.

Example of simple long running block that I would like to run without blocking my current session:

```
DO
$do$
begin
   FOR i IN 1..1000000
   loop
      // some long running inserts
      insert into my_table(x) values (i);
      commit;
   end loop;
end $do$;
```

Comment: Have you tried pgagent? https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/5.0/pgagent_jobs.html

Comment: @richyen I am not sure how to access it. In  pgAdmin "Help/Quick search" nothing is found for "pgAgent". In Application Stack Builder I also don't  see an option to install "pgAgent". The docs don't give enough information about the installation.

Comment: Are you using enterprisedb postgres, or regular, community postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have a single statement at a time running in a single PostgreSQL database session. The solution is to start a second session: then one session can execute the script, and you can concurrently do other work in the other session.

Comment: That's totally correct. But I would like to start a long-running statement, close my session, and later return back and check the results. And as a bonus it will protect from connection loss in a middle of the work in case of bad network.

Comment: That's a reasonable requirement. Start your script with `nohup psql -f script.sql &`, or whatever is the equivalent on your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to this new PostgreSQL extension [pg_dbms_job](https://github.com/MigOpsRepos/pg_dbms_job), it implements all features provided by Oracle DBMS_JOB with the same procedures like dbms_job.submit().